# how can i get rotation vector from matrix4x4 in xna?

Tags: matrix, vector

i want to get rotation vector from matrix to realize some parent-children system for models.

```
 Matrix bonePos = link.Bone.Transform * World;
 Matrix m = Matrix.CreateTranslation(link.Offset)
       * Matrix.CreateScale(link.gameObj.Scale.X, link.gameObj.Scale.Y, 
                 link.gameObj.Scale.Z)
       * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians(link.gameObj.Rotation.Y),
                 MathHelper.ToRadians(link.gameObj.Rotation.X),
                 MathHelper.ToRadians(link.gameObj.Rotation.Z))
//need rotation vector from bone matrix here (now it's global model rotation vector)
        * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.Y),
                  MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.X),
                  MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.Z))
         * Matrix.CreateTranslation(bonePos.Translation);
link.gameObj.World = m;
```

where :
  link - struct with children model settings, like position, rotation etc.

 And link.Bone - Parent Bone

Comment: there is a Matrix.Decompose method, if thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

```
Matrix.Decompose
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.decompose.aspx